# Vue single file component - Async functions aren't being transpiled by babel

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2, babeljs

I have a small vue app which contains some `.vue` single file components. One of the components has some simple async functions which I would like converted to ES5 friendly code via the "async to generator" and "regenerator" babel transforms. I have async functions in other `.js` files that are being converted correctly, so I know the transforms are configured properly and working as they should. Also, other babel transforms are being applied successfully to the `.vue` file, so it seems the js portion of the `.vue` is being piped through babel, but I'm at a bit of a loss why these functions aren't being converted properly. For example in the `.vue` file I have the method:

```
addQuestion: async function () {
    try {
        /* Test code */
        const tempLit = `this is a template string - ${num}`;
        let temp = 3;
        /********************/

        const id = await Api.addQuestion(this.form.id); //responds with Id
        const question = { order: this.questions.length + 1, id: id, isNew: true, deleted: false };
        this.form.questions.push(question);
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: document.body.scrollHeight }, 500);
    } catch (e) {
        this.error(e);
    }
}
```

this is being converted to the following code in the bundle by webpack:

```
addQuestion: async function addQuestion() {
    try {
        /* Test code */
        var tempLit = "this is a template string - " + num;
        var temp = 3;
        /********************/

        var id = await _FormsApi2.default.addQuestion(this.form.id); //responds with Id
        var question = { order: this.questions.length + 1, id: id, isNew: true, deleted: false };
        this.form.questions.push(question);
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: document.body.scrollHeight }, 500);
    } catch (e) {
        this.error(e);
    }
}
```

As you can see from little sample of test code in between the comments, some ES6 features are being converted successfully which suggests the js is being run through babel.

So i guess my question is, is there anything specific that need to be done to get ES7 features such as async working in `.vue` files?

My current webpack config looks like this:

```
{
    entry: [
        "babel-polyfill", // Set up an ES6-ish environment
        "whatwg-fetch", // fetch polyfill
    ].concat(modules),// application entry point
    output: {
        filename: "./assets/scripts/vue/bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        noParse: /es6-promise\.js$/,
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: "vue-loader",
                options: {
                    loaders: {
                        js: {
                            loader: 'babel-loader',
                            options: {
                                presets: ['es2015']
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: file => (/node_modules/.test(file) && !/\.vue\.js/.test(file)),
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    plugins: [
                        "transform-runtime",
                        "transform-regenerator", // not needed in Chrome or Firefox. Soon won't be needed in Edge or Safari.
                        "transform-async-to-generator",
                        "transform-es2015-template-literals"
                    ],
                    presets: ["es2015"]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[a|c]ss$/,
                loader: 'style!css!sass'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        // responsible for identifying common files and generating a shared bundle
        //new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        //    name: 'common' // Specify the common bundle's name.
        //}),
        new WebpackNotifierPlugin(),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue': "vue/dist/vue.min.js"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was fixed by adding the babel stage 3 preset